# Does google Contact api support 2-legged OAuth 2.0?

Tags: gmail, contacts, impersonation, accounts

I want to impersonate Gmail accounts Contacts but could not find the way how to use 2-legged OAuth 2.0 to do that.
I am using C# Google client liberary.

Comment: Can you add more details? Which language you want to use? Is it a web application? Do you want import contacts? And please, do not post the same question twice.

Comment: We just started the migration process from OAuth1 to OAuth2 for Google Contacts API, using Google Apps Script - still gathering information - any help / hint / code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google didn't provide any new Contact API for OAuth 2.0. You can use Google.GData.Contacts.dll to perform Contact OAuth 2.0 impersonation. Use GOAuth2RequestFactory object to assign Access Token to contact service.

```
                OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
           {
               AccessToken = _AccessToken
           };

            GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "GamailContactsReader", parameters);

            // Connecting the Contats service.
            ContactsService service = new Google.GData.Contacts.ContactsService("GamailContactsReader");
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;               

            GroupsQuery groupQuery = new GroupsQuery(GroupsQuery.CreateGroupsUri(_EmailAddress));
            groupQuery.NumberToRetrieve = int.MaxValue;

            GroupsFeed groupFeed = service.Query(groupQuery);
```